# Firebase Mutilple Item Upload not working

Tags: python, django, pyrebase

I need help to upload mutiple images in firebase

```
for files in local_image:

        cloud_img = "images/example" + str(random.randint(1, 18596)) 
        storage.child(cloud_img).put(files, user['idToken'])
        imgurl = storage.child(cloud_img).get_url(user['idToken'])


        def Convert(string): 
            li = list(string.split(",")) 
            return li 
        urllist = imgurl
        # print(Convert(urllist))
        x = Convert(urllist)


        data = {
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "phone": phone,
        "password": password,
        "image": x

        }
        print(x)
        results = db.child("users").push(data, user['idToken'])
```

I am using python to push data but images url is saving only single url in databse

please help me to figure it out

Comment: `pyrebase` doesn't support batch upload so you need to iterate the files and upload them one by one

Comment: actually doing this files are storing in storage but im getting only single url of image out of oop but in loop im getting muti urls